# Heroku logs stop working

Tags: heroku

I need help.

I'm using Heroku as my server Node JS. Until several time when I'm using `heroku logs` the console are showing the logs. then suddenly when I restart my computer and I use `heroku logs` I'm getting logs error which are

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\...\heroku\tmp\heroku-script-884953635:14:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at startup (node.js:159:18)
    at node.js:444:3
```

Is there something I've missing here? also, I've checked `heroku addons` and the result is `No add-ons for app myproject.`

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "heroku logs" worked for me three months ago, and I am on window 10.

The logs stopped working for me too.

And, I **uninstall** the heroku-toolbelt on my window, and **re-install** it again.

The "heroku logs" works for me again.